# Looking for example of raw json configuration file per builtType in Android Studio/Gradle

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android App and need a JSON configuration file for AAD B2C in the raw directory which is called by like this:

```
    PublicClientApplication.createMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication(activity.getApplicationContext(),
          R.raw.auth_config_multiple_account,...)
```

I need a `R.raw.auth_config_multiple_account` for each buildType (and possibly flavor). Let's just assume I need a dev, test, prod. I read this article on [providing alternate resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources) and this one for [Configure build types](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types), but I don't know exactly how this is supposed to work.

I assumed it might be a subdirectory in raw which is named for the buildType, but that does not seem to be the case. Does anybody have a simple example of this?

Also which buildType is used when you press play on Android Studio and run the app in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in case anybody else has questions around this. [This article](https://www.journaldev.com/21533/android-build-types-product-flavors) and [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors) helped.

I went into the ***project*** view in Project explorer, created a **debug** directory (to match my debug buildType in the build.gradle) in the src directory (making it a peer of main, test and androidTest), created a **res** directory under the new debug directory and a **raw** directory under the new res directory. I copied the auth_config_multiple_account.json file into it and altered the configuration to test it. All worked ok.